# Using Python to get current time in yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss.000Z format and also add days

Tags: python, date, datetime, time

I'm using Python and I need to get the time in a certain format that this API uses.  So I need to get current time in the format of yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss.000Z and then also create a new date in the future by adding a number of days to it.

So if I could get the current time of 2017-08-19T07:00:00.000Z and add 30 days to it to get 2017-09-18T07:00:00.000Z.  What would be the easiest way to write this in Python?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Current date

```
import datetime
now = datetime.datetime.now()
format_iso_now = now.isoformat()
```

Add 10 days

```
from datetime import timedelta
later = now + timedelta(days=10)
format_later_iso = later.isoformat()
```

Output

```
print(format_iso_now, format_later_iso)

2017-08-20T02:43:07.177167 2017-08-30T02:43:07.177167
```

And to match your needs

```
print(now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S:%fZ'))

2017-08-20 02:48:00:103856Z
```

More details on [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html)

Comment: Awesome thanks!!  What if I needed the current time to be in UTC of my current time zone in US CST and account for daylight savings time?  Right now it would be UTC = now + timedelta(hours=5)  but later in the year it would be UTC = now + timedelta(hours=6)

Comment: @JasonMurray i don't understand your question. Can you explain?

Comment: Oh i think i found the answer i would use utcnow instead of now